# What should I do if app didn't receive any ad from adWhirl in iOS

Tags: ios, iad, adwhirl

I am integrated adWhirl in my iOS app successfully. I read in Apple docs that , if your app don't have any ad to show then you should hide banner. But in case of AdWhirl it is written in [FAQ of AdWhirl](http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)

> Does the AdWhirl SDK check network connectivity before attempting to request ads and prevent battery drainage?
>
> Yes. The client SDK checks to see if network connectivity is available before allowing any ad requests to run. If no network connectivity is available, no ad requests are made. Therefore, note that since no ad requests are made, no callbacks will be made.

So how can I handle this situation? Does Apple reject my application? 
Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the AdWhirl adapter for iAd, it looks like it initializes the AdBannerview as so:

```
 ADBannerView *iAdView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Then only in the `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` callback is the frame of the ad set as so:

```
 CGRect newFrame = banner.frame;
 newFrame.origin.x = newFrame.origin.y = 0;
 banner.frame = newFrame;
```

So I don't think you have to worry abou this as the iAd adapter for AdWhirl makes sure that the size of the ad is CGRectZero until an actual ad comes in.